# inserting images having different ratios in a div without changing the dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have created a div having a particular height and width. Inside that I have inserted images. The problem is if the images are of same dimensions, then divs are similar. But if the images are of different dimensions, then the divs also change.

For example, have a look on the page below:
http://versatilemobitech.com/portfolio/

The dimesion of all images are of 180*200 pixels, that's why all the divs are looking similar (square sizes boxes having white background). 
My question is can't we make a div having a particular dimension and then insert images of different aspect ratios without changing the dimensions of the div as it could save time from resizing the images to same dimensions all the time.

Comment: you can fix the height and give max-width

Comment: for your information i have given you the link. You can try using  that. what ever i tried i have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

add style to your image styles

```
max-width: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
```

OR

```
max-width: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
width: auto; 
height: 100%;
```

it should work

edit : Your parent div must have the property `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
.image{
max-width:180px;
max-height:200px;
}
```

this will adjust your image with aspect ratio